Cannot get emails from screen flow if previewed as guest user in Experience Site
Hey I have started learning the way to use flows in my experience website.
So I have created a basic screen flow to get input name and email and added email action to send emails to the entered email on the screen.
So if I use the screen flow on the Experience site. I'm receiving the mails only if I preview as authenticated user, but for the guest user the mails are not received.
So how can I setup or change my approach to let the guest users receive mails if entered their email address.
Thanks in advance.

I'm guessing this will be related to the permissions for the site guest user. If you turn on debug logs for that user you might find something that helps, afraid I don't have any direct knowledge of it!

Make sure you have correct mail id for guest user.(https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390039&type=1)

Hey guys thanks for the valuable responses. Actual the problem was with my guest profile as the guest profile will have invalid email as default. Changing it to valid org email address solved my problem.
